# How to find the norm of $ \Lambda x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{n\sqrt{6}}$ in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\ell^2$, i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_n^2 < \infty$. Define:

$$\Lambda x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{n\sqrt{6}}$$

Find $\| \Lambda \|_2$

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it's easy to see that for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $\ell^2$ such that $\|(x_n)\|=1$, we have $\displaystyle |\Lambda x| \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$:

$$|\Lambda x|^2 = |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{n\sqrt{6}}|^2 \leq |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^2|\cdot|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n^2}|=\frac{\pi^2}{36}$$

How can I show that $\| \Lambda \|$ is indeed equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{6}$?

Comment: What happens for  $x=(1/\sqrt6, 1/(2\sqrt6), 1/(3\sqrt6), \ldots)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to recall a general corollary of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|\langle x,y \rangle | \leq \| x \| \| y \|$ *and* the inequality is strict except when $x$ is a scalar multiple of $y$. So choose $x_n$ to be a (nonzero) scalar multiple of the sequence $y_n = \frac{1}{n \sqrt{6}}$ and you will get your result.

Comment: @math.n00b You can choose $x_n$ to be $y_n/\| y \| = 6y_n/\pi$ if you want to work on the unit sphere. It should be clear that such an $x_n$ is on the unit sphere, by the homogeneity of a norm.